# What is the meaning of compatibility in this context?

Tags: terminology, relations

I'm reviewing some classical analysis using a text from the 90's. When I took a course using Rudin last year, I never learned this terminology.

> If $x\le y$, then $x+z\le y+z$.  **(compatibility of $\le$ and $+$)**
>
> If $0\le x$ and $0\le y$, then $0\le xy$. **(compatibility of $\le$ and $\cdot$)**

It appears, based on the first definition, "compatibility of $x$ and $y$" means performing the same amount of the $y$-operation on both sides of the $x$-relation preserves the relation. If this is the correct definition, why isn't the second definition phrased as "If $x\le y$ and $z\ge 0$..."? Also, do we use "compatibility of $x$ and $y$" and "compatibility of $y$ and $x$" interchangeable, or is order of importance?

Comment: I'm  not clear what you mean by "the same amount of the y-operation".  In fact, I would not say there **is** a "y-operation".  There are two quantities, x and y, and two operations, multiplication and addition.  There is NO "compatibility of x and y" or "compatibility of y and x".  It is the operations, not the quantities that are "compatible".  (Unless you just meant "x" and "y" to mean any two operations- which would be confusing since you have already used "x" and "y" to mean quantities.)  In any case, "compatibility" here just means they "play well together"- there are simple relationships

Comment: I did indeed reuse the $x$ and $y$ variables when I should not have; I meant for them to stand in for the relation and operation, respectively. So “compatibility” is not some rigorously defined term?

Comment: Yes, it can be rigorously defined.

Answer (score 1):

The comaptibility is a concept which relates relations and operations both defined over the same set. In general the following definition of compatibility is assumed: given any set $X$, a relation $\sim$ over $X$ and an operation $\ast$ over $X$, we say $\sim$ is compatible with $\ast$ iff $$\forall a,b,c,d \in X \big(a \sim b \land c \sim d \Rightarrow a \ast c \sim b \ast d\big)\,.$$
Now you have $X = \mathbb R$ (I think), $\le$ instead of $\sim$ and the multiplication $\cdot$ instead of $\ast$.
If you choose $b$ and $d$ equal, you will obtain the first compatibility you mention. The second is simple: let $a$ and $c$ be equal to $0$.

Comment: Letting $a,c=0$ would not show compatibility by the definition you provided.

Comment: Yes, it does. Check it better.

Comment: Seriously? Your definition literally says to be “compatible” it must hold for all $a,b,c,d$ not some $a,b,c,d$. Fixing $b,d$ to 0 does not show in any way shape or form the statement holds for all $b,d$. I encourage you to “check it better”.

Comment: *fixing $a,c$ to 0.

Comment: Ok. First of all: if a property holds for **all** objects in a *universe of discourse*, it also holds for **some** of the objects of the same universe, or not? Now, if you let $a=c=0$, you will have $0 \le b \land 0 \le d \Rightarrow 0 \le bd$, for every $b,d$, and you have the second compatibility you mentioned. Is it ok now?

Comment: No, it’s not okay, as the property does not hold for all objects in an ordered field, making your justification for the definition spurious. I think it would be better to label the second definition as “(Compatibility of Nonnegatives)”.

Comment: Call it how you desire. Note that I have never said my definition is equivalent to the propositions you mentioned. I gave you the general definition of compatibility (which you can accept or not, with the correspondent consequences) and then deduced your book's compatibilities.